# how to load pdf in binary format on UIWebview iOS?

Tags: objective-c, pdf, ios7, uiwebview

I want to open a pdf file when user clicks on download button, but the data loaded is decode, how can i convert response data to be as a pdf file? i am not loading it from local document or bundle.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *requestObj  = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webViewForDocsView loadRequest:requestObj];
[self.view addSubview:webViewForDocsView];
```

Answer (score 0):

To load raw data first create a NSData object with the content of the url response, then load the data by specifying the mime type and data, like the code snippet:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"binary file link"];
NSError *error;

/**
 *  GET the data from a url link
 */
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url
                                     options:NSDataReadingUncached
                                       error:&error];

if (error) { // validation
    NSLog(@"data error: %@", error);

}

UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.view addSubview:webView];

/**
 *  Load the request fro mthe binaray data
 */
[webView loadData:data
         MIMEType:@"application/pdf"
 textEncodingName:@"utf-8"
          baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"]];
```

Comment: thanks buddy, i had tried this but i didn't want to download data before hand. i wanted to directly load the url on UIWebview, but loaded pdf was encrypted and now it is solved.